# detect change in column value?

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

This is how my table looks

```
page  time
x      0
x      1
x      2
y      0
y      1
x      0
x      1
x      2
x      3 
z      0
z      1
z      2
z      3
```

I am plotting a graph based on values of x,y,z.

So My graph looks like--

[image]

The height of each bar is determined by peak value of respective page.

I tried something like this

```
`$query="select `page`,`time` from `table` where session_id="$session_id" GroupBy ...how do i go about this.";
```

but it gives me only 3 bars.But I want the no. of bar depending on the switch (switch from peak value to 0.In above table there are 4 such switch and thus there are 4 bars in my graph.)

I hope I am clear with my question.
I am not able figure out the query.

**UPDATE-->**
I am developing a tracker which basically keeps track of all the links clicked by a user and time spend on it.So the switch can be from X to Y to X to Z..It can be random.Thats why i am confused.

**UPDATE 2:**
suppose if I click a link that redirects me to page x when I have already spent time==2 at the very same page x...then only max(time) is returned,I need the previous max time on X **+** current max time on X.
In simple words,If i visit the same page again..I dont want the last recorded time to get suppressed if if spend more time on it comparitively,Instead I want to add up the time..

Comment: Please confirm why you consider two "x" series in your result. Is this because there is a "gap" between the first series of "x" (rows 0, 1, 2) and the second one (rows 5, 6, 7, 8)? Or is this because of the value "0"?

Comment: I will just add up a little explanation.2 min

Comment: The main issue here is that you are assuming the first `x,0` pair is different from the second `x,0` pair. If you really need them to be different, then you will have to add a discriminator to the table (ID) or maybe create a queary that adds the ID dynamically with a variable... which is not quite efficient.

Comment: @MESSIAH . . . SQL Tables are inherently unordered.  You seem to be depending on the ordering in your table.  Do you have an auto-incrementing ID or creation date to specify the order?

Comment: @GordonLinoff:yes i do have both of them!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, that you want to group based on a specific order of the columns, not column page.

Here's a workaround:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (id int auto_increment, `page` varchar(1), `time` int, primary key (id))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`page`, `time`)
VALUES
    ('x', 0),
    ('x', 1),
    ('x', 2),
    ('y', 0),
    ('y', 1),
    ('x', 0),
    ('x', 1),
    ('x', 2),
    ('x', 3),
    ('z', 0),
    ('z', 1),
    ('z', 2),
    ('z', 3)
;


select page, max(time) from (
select 
t.*
, IF(@prev != page, @counter := @counter + 1, @counter) as my_groups
, @prev:=page
from
Table1 t
, (select @prev:=NULL, @counter:=0) v 
order by id
) sq
group by my_groups
```

See it working live [here in an sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7f9c4/1/0).

Note that I introduced the column `id`. It's just a column that helps to guarantee an order. In a database there's no first or last row. The order in which you inserted the rows is not the guaranteed order when you simply select from the table.

Explanatation:

Here

```
Table1 t
, (select @prev:=NULL, @counter:=0) v
```

we initialize our variables inside the query. It's the same as writing

```
SET @prev:=NULL;
SET @counter:=0;
SELECT ... FROM Table1 ORDER BY whatever...
```

Now in the SELECT part of the subquery

```
, IF(@prev != page, @counter := @counter + 1, @counter) as my_groups
, @prev:=page
```

these 2 rows are important in the order they are written. The second row assigns the value of the read row to the variable @prev. In the first row we check if @prev is different from the row which is read by SELECT. If yes, we increase our counter variable @counter by 1, if no we leave it as it is.

The subquery (a bit modified to make it more clear what happens)

```
select 
IF(@prev != page, @counter := @counter + 1, @counter) as my_groups
, page
, @prev
, @prev:=page
, time
from
Table1 t
, (select @prev:=NULL, @counter:=0) v
order by id
```

returns this result then:

```
| MY_GROUPS | PAGE |  @PREV | @PREV:=PAGE | TIME |
--------------------------------------------------
|         0 |    x | (null) |           x |    0 |
|         0 |    x |      x |           x |    1 |
|         0 |    x |      x |           x |    2 |
|         1 |    y |      x |           y |    0 |
|         1 |    y |      y |           y |    1 |
|         2 |    x |      y |           x |    0 |
|         2 |    x |      x |           x |    1 |
|         2 |    x |      x |           x |    2 |
|         2 |    x |      x |           x |    3 |
|         3 |    z |      x |           z |    0 |
|         3 |    z |      z |           z |    1 |
|         3 |    z |      z |           z |    2 |
|         3 |    z |      z |           z |    3 |
```

The outer query is simple then. We group by the column `my_groups` (we aliased this row with it)

```
IF(@prev != page, @counter := @counter + 1, @counter) as my_groups
```

and for each group we return the page and the maximum time.

Hope it's all clear now. Feel free to ask, though, if that's not the case :)

Comment: can you explain it a bit..i am new to php,mysql...and more in to javascript!!!I am not able to understand whats happening

Comment: what would be better,firing query or processing it in my php script.??

Comment: Hard to tell. If it's really that performance critical, I'd measure if there's a difference. If not, why bother? You already got a working solution here.

Comment: thanks,i have understood most part of it..but there are still few question marks about it...
(1).what is t.*
    (2).Table1 t
   (3).v
   (4).sq
.....i have never ever come across such queries.And after looking at your solution i want to learn more about syntaxing and creating advance queries..some books or just googling??

Comment: t, v and sq are aliases. It saves typing work and subqueries must have an alias.

Comment: alias??coming across it for the first time..do you have some link that describes it???

Comment: There's not much to describe. It's just a name after a column or a table name (optionally with an `AS` between it, like in `SELECT column1 AS my_first_column FROM incredible_long_table_name AS ilt`). That's it. If you want to learn about SQL from the start, this is a good read about joins http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html Apart from that you can find plenty of tutorials on the net. The official documentation of MySQL is excellent with plenty of examples. That should be enough for the start, a good book doesn't hurt though.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33966/discussion-between-messiah-and-fancypants)

Comment: ran n to a problem..updated my problem...I tweaked with your query but in vain...can you have look at the updated question ...??Plz

Comment: This solution is solely based on the fact, that the column page changes. To reflect clicks on the same page in the database you definitely have to introduce a column in this table that holds this information. Based on what you have now, simply page and time, it's not possible.

Comment: ok ,so I will insert a column named `detect_change` and give it a boolean value..will that help??
I will give 1 on every page load...how do I modify my query say i have 1 @ every page change...?

Comment: i dint find any tutorial that explains sql the way i wanted...so i eventually ended up following your answers on SO..that really hepled!!!

Answer (score -1):

you can do something like:

```
select page, max(time) from table where session_id = ...
group by page
```

but according to your table structure above, it will give only 3 values since 1st and 3rd x would be treated as same. This is because of the way your table is defined. So you will get 3 graphs and not 4.

Comment: no no no...i know this..but the problem is when i want to detect the switch...peak to zero...It may vary from 3 to 10,15,20 depending on the no. of switches...am i clear